# How to make a loop over this?

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to get metadata from multiple urls.  I have this code:

```
from urllib import urlopen
from lxml import etree

f = urlopen('http://www.google.com',
        'http://www.youtube.com').read()

tree = etree.HTML(f)
m = tree.xpath( "//meta")

for i in m:
    print etree.tostring(i)
```

but the result will only show the metadata for the first url given. i guess i have to make a loop so the function will run on the second url as well but I am unsure about how to do this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`urlopen` only accepts a single URL, so you can’t fetch multiple websites that way—especially not at once. You will have to it once for each URL:

```
for url in ('http://www.google.com', 'http://www.youtube.com'):
    f = urlopen(url).read()
    tree = etree.HTML(f)
    …
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, as you can probably tell I'm pretty inexperienced when it comes to this so this may sound stupid. but do I leave the remaining code in my original post it the same positions? the 

m = tree.xpath( "//meta")

for i in m:
    print etree.tostring(i)

bit?

Comment: Yeah, that should work. In doubt: Just try it out :)

Comment: for some reason it now seems to skip the first website given and gives the metadata for the second website only..who knows..

Comment: You need to have your code also indented, so it’s part of the for-body and is executed for each URL.